# Catch net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED in an Angular app

Tags: angular, google-chrome

We have an Angular4 app and sometimes in Chrome we get the error

> net :: ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

when loading resources (images, etc). This usually happens when the IP of the client / Chrome changes.

Has anyone any idea how to catch this error in Angular?

Comment: potentially irrelevant question - why would you want to handle this error? this is network error and chrome is handling it.

Comment: The Angular app is a single-page app. The resources, js-files, etc. are loaded in the background, so the user does not see this error (you can see this error in the developer console)

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for this issue is to create a never ending request like a SSE request. And then detect an error (if you really need a global listener).

This example is only really useful when you want to reload the page when a network error occurs. There doesn't seem to be a global error listener available for these kind of errors, but you can also apply this to specific short requests to your server (like loading images). Just register an error handler on your specific (instead of global) request.

### Javascript SSE example

In this case it is enough to reload the page. The `net :: ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` error occurs on my case when I switch on or off a VPN connection. I only want to reload the page thereafter.

```js
var source = new EventSource("YOUR_SSE_ENDPOINT");
source.onmessage = function(event) {};
source.onerror = function() { 
    source.close();
    console.log("Reload the page after 10 seconds because of network error");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        location.reload();
    }, 10*1000);
};
```

### HTML5 / Javascript Image example

It will as I said, also work on other specific requests, like with an image:

```html
<img src="image_link_where_network_changed_error_occurs" onerror="location.reload()">
```

You should be aware of the fact that it does not filter the kind of error that occurs, so when you image url gives a 404 error, it will reload the page. Which might not be what you want.

### Try to reload image

Another use case is to try and reload the image for 5 times. In the meantime the network could be restored and load the image, or if not (or the image returns 404) it will stop after 5 times.

```html
<script>
function reloadImage(image) {
    if (!image.hasOwnProperty('counter')){
      image.counter = 0;
    }
    
    if (image.counter < 5){
      setTimeout(function (){
          image.src += '?' + +Math.random();
          image.counter += 1;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
</script>

<img src="image_link_where_network_changed_error_occurs" onerror="reloadImage(this)">
```